# Rails - Enumerize case insensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a model I have in a Rails project, one field is used with Enumerize as follows:

```
enumerize :status, in: %i[draft active], default: :active
```

If I used "active" as input it works, "ACTIVE" however gives an inclusion error.

I tried to get around this by registering a before_validation callback

```
before_validation :downcase_fields

def downcase_fields
  status.downcase! if status.present?
end
```

but this doesn't work as well.

How can I make an enumerizable field case insensitive in Rails?

Comment: I assume that `downcase_fields` is defined in your model and not elsewhere? You don't say so have to assume.

Comment: yes in the model :D

Comment: You gave us the bare minimum code to inspect. Obviously there is nothing wrong with the code you've shown us. So some other piece of your code is causing the problem.

Comment: You need to add relevant model and controller code so we can see what else is also going on. Also add something like `puts "#{status} being downcased" ` into your downcase_fields method and look in the web console to see that it's actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerize doesn't allow setting any value that is not one of the original acceptable set. For example if this is how the field is set in the model

```
enumerize :status, in: %i[draft active], default: :active
```

trying `status = :Active` would not even set the field.

The only I could do it, was through the setter (when the value is being set)

```
  def status=(value)
    super(value&.downcase)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, You can check on console by adding debugger in downcase_fields methos. Or you can simply add the validation check :
uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}

Comment: Hi Anita, welcome to SO
The problem here is that because of Enumerize, the field is not even set if I tried setting with any value that is not in the original set.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).